# QGIS geometry generator to SLD

Tags: qgis, geoserver, shapefile, sld, geometry-generator

In QGIS I'm using the geometry generator to visualize a point shape file as a line with the simple code:

[image]

And then I'm doing a graduated styling according to the burial value of those points:

[image]

So the end result looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to upload this to the GeoServer and use the same styling. But the SLD export of QGIS doesn't support the geometry generator. I can't find any documentation to write this SLD myself. I'm not even sure it's possible in a SLD file. If not, does anybody know a work-around? Maybe exporting the generated line as a line shapefile?

Comment: check out https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#geometric-functions - you can probably build it with those functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new shapefile using the same expression created for the Geometry generator in Processing toolbox > Vector geometry > Geometry by expression. 
This will create a  line shapefile that you can export using the SLD exporter.

Comment: Thanks, precisely what i needed.